# Change "You are now logged out" text

Tags: filters, login, wp-login-form, logout

I want to wrap `<strong></strong>` around the words "logged out":

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse17709_gettext', 10, 2 );
function wpse17709_gettext( $custom_translation, $login_texts ) {

    // Messages
    if ( 'You are now logged out.' == $login_texts ) { return ''; } // Log out message

    return $translation
}
```

...however adding HTML elements to the text string breaks my page.

How can I add `<strong></strong>` to this message text? Is there a means other than `gettext`?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13644204/1815847

Comment: keep in mind adding things to the `gettext` filter has performance implications

Comment: @TomJNowell Thus far, I'm using `gettext` for the page title, user name label and password label. Would you deem this frequency of use of the said filter to be low enough to avoid [known performance concerns](https://pippinsplugins.com/dangers-gettext-filter)?

Comment: @Sven Thanks. I've refined to meet my requirements: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/215294/41545

Comment: See: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/289500/133699

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This allows for the message to be overwritten specifically for the `loggedout` message while leaving all other messages alone. [Here is more documentation on the filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_login_errors/).

```
add_filter( 'wp_login_errors', 'my_logout_message' );

function my_logout_message( $errors ){

    if ( isset( $errors->errors['loggedout'] ) ){
        $errors->errors['loggedout'][0] = 'This is the <strong style="color:red;">logged out</strong> message.';
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: Most impressive. I wasn't aware of this means of filtering.

Comment: Usually when using filters you want to pass a `parameter` to the function, to get the data you are looking to filter. When it is an `object`, in this case, I do not want to destroy it. I only reset a specific value that may exist in the object. Honestly, I learned something too! Great question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Sven's recommended solution and Tom J Nowell's warning about `gettext()` (see comments for both), I've fashioned the following solution:

```
add_filter( 'login_message', 'wpse_215289_custom_logout_message' );
add_action( 'login_head','wpse_215289_custom_login_head' );

// Detect logout and add custom message.
function wpse_215289_custom_logout_message() 
{
    //check to see if it's the logout screen
    if ( isset($_GET['loggedout']) && TRUE == $_GET['loggedout'] ){
        $message = "<p class='message'>Custom log-out message.</p>";
    }
    return $message;
} 

// Remove original message via CSS.
function wpse_215289_custom_login_head() 
{
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    .message:nth-child(2) { display:none; }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: I down voted this answer because of the solution to hide the other message with CSS. I have done it many times, but when you can output exactly what you want it is much better. If you edit the answer with your implementation you and I will both gain some points! ;) ( just 1 for me, and the down vote will go away ).

Answer (score 1):

Change “You are now logged out” text using filter **login_messages**

```
function custom_logout_message(){
  return 'You are not login!';
}
add_filter( 'login_messages', 'custom_logout_message' );
```

Comment: @Clarus Dignus, you can change using filter "login_messages", an I have used in my answer.